# How to read txt file and copy the content into a google spreadsheet file using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning,

I have a text file on my Google drive with a number of row and columns filled by data.

**Data Example**

```
ANNO    MESE    GIORNO    D01    D02    D03    D04    D05
2012    4       20        0      2      0      0      0
2012    4       21        0      0      3      0      0
2012    4       22        0      4      0      0      0
2012    4       23        0      0      0      6      0
2012    4       24        0      0      0      0      7
```

I would like to access this file and copy the content into a Google spreadsheet file using a Google spreadsheet script (javascript Language).

I tried to use the following code, but since I'm new to the Language, I didn't get how to access the data.

```js
function LoadData() {
  
  var FldrId = '1-Ao-MQMv_VxKF5uajG1o4j5dhVRWDk76';
  var FileName = 'TEST_Report_USA.txt';
  
  //Reference to the folder    
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(FldrId);

  //Get files by that name
  var allFilesInFolder = fldr.getFilesByName(FileName);
  
  Logger.log('allFilesInFolder: ' + allFilesInFolder);

  if (allFilesInFolder.hasNext() === false) {
  return false;
  };
  
  var cntFiles = 0;
  //Even if it's only one file, must iterate a while loop in order to access the file (Google drive will allow multiple files of the same name)
  while (allFilesInFolder.hasNext()) {
    var thisFile = allFilesInFolder.next();
    cntFiles = cntFiles + 1;
    Logger.log('File Count: ' + cntFiles);

    var docContent = thisFile.getAs('text/plain');
    Logger.log('docContent : ' + docContent );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You forgot to post your code snippet, where you are facing a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this Language. I put part of the code I tried, but I don't know how to access the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification? This modified script supposes that you use the container-bound script of Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve the blob from file using `getBlob()`.
- Retrieve the text data from the blob using `getDataAsString()`.
- Parse the text data to csv data using `Utilities.parseCsv()`.
- Put the csv data to Spreadsheet using `setValues()`.

For these modification points, please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
while (allFilesInFolder.hasNext()) {
  var thisFile = allFilesInFolder.next();
  cntFiles = cntFiles + 1;
  Logger.log('File Count: ' + cntFiles);

  var docContent = thisFile.getAs('text/plain');
  Logger.log('docContent : ' + docContent );
}
```

#### To :

```
var delimiter = "\t"; // Added
while (allFilesInFolder.hasNext()) {
  var thisFile = allFilesInFolder.next();
  cntFiles = cntFiles + 1;
  Logger.log('File Count: ' + cntFiles);

  var docContent = thisFile.getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Modified
  Logger.log('docContent : ' + docContent );
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(docContent, delimiter); // Added
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv); // Added
}
```

#### Note :

- In this modified script, the csv data is put to the spreadsheet of bound script.
- Please modify `delimiter`. In this script, `\t` is used as the delimiter.

#### References :

- [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob())
- [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString())
- [Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String,Char))
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem! I only added the definition of variable "ss"

Comment: @Nicola Trenti I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.